# Getting PHP warning when condition is false

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom meta box using [WPAlchemy class](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) to add option for related posts.

Following code is working file in WP-Admin, and also in frontend only if i add related posts to the custom form created with meta box.

However if i leave this empty, i am getting following warning message

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'topics' in
>   /homepages/9/d416241127/htdocs/tw/u2me/wp-content/themes/u2me/single.php
>   on line 37

Here line 37 is `if ($my_meta['topics']) {`

in other words i am getting warning message when this condition should return false.

---

I have used following code to create custom meta:

```
<?php while($mb->have_fields_and_multi('topics')): ?>
<?php $mb->the_group_open(); ?>

    <?php $mb->the_field('title'); ?>
    <label>Title</label>
    <p style="margin-top:0px;"><input type="text" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

    <?php $mb->the_field('link'); ?>
    <label>URL</label>
    <p style="margin-top:0px;"><input type="text" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

    <p><a href="#" class="dodelete button">Remove Topic</a></p>

    <br/>

<?php $mb->the_group_close(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

---

and used following code in single.php to show the values stored using above code:

```
<?php
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_related_topics_meta',TRUE);
if ($my_meta['topics']) {
    echo '<ul class="hero-subtitle">';
    foreach ($my_meta['topics'] as $topic) {
 ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $topic['link']; ?>"><?php echo $topic['title']; ?></a></li>
  <?php     } 
     echo '</ul>';
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if ($my_meta['topics']) {
```

AS

```
if (!empty($my_meta['topics'])) {
```

may be this will help you